# Magento CLI indexer catalog_url brakes url rewrites

Tags: php, magento, url-rewriting

I have a strange issue with Magento 1.7.0.2

When I reindex "Catalog URL Rewrites" via cli

> php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url

I get pathes generated **without .html** and links in shop are not working.

When I reindex it with Index Management tool in administration, everything is ok.

**Product URL Suffix** and **Category URL Suffix** are set to **.html**

Anyone have any clues?

**SOLVED**

The problem was that any scripts was not able to get any configs using 
Mage::getStoreConfig()

**Flushing Magento Cache and Cache Storage solved problem.**